# Apply directly changes for content Apache Sling

Tags: maven, osgi, bundle, osgi-bundle, sling

How can i configure apache `Sling` to take automatically modifications that i have done in `.html` oder `.jsp` file (in content) ?

For the moment i should every time rebuild the maven  project.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Eclipse, you can use the [Sling IDE tooling for Eclipse](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/development/ide-tooling.html).

The Eclipse tooling consists of a set of plugins which help you quickly deploy your changes to a running Sling instance, whether you are using OSGi bundles or content-package projects.

It also offers other features, like

- Sightly support
- Enhanced debugging support
- A content navigator

[image]